# Natural communication problems that are hard only for number-in-hand protocols?

Tags: communication-complexity

I am looking for tools to lower bound the deterministic, blackboard, number-in-hand communication complexity of a certain function which is roughly speaking $f : \{0,1\}^k \times \ldots \times \{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$, where $f$ has $k$ arguments each known by one player in the protocol. I have proven that both the nondeterministic and co-nondeterministic communication complexity of $f$ in the number-in-hand model is small, $\widetilde O(k)$. But, I conjecture that the deterministic complexity should be as high as possible, $\Omega(k^2)$.

Initially, I had hoped that one could resolve the conjecture by embedding a hard two-player communication problem in this model. But, while I haven't finished the proof, I think now it may be the case that for any partition of the $k$ inputs of $f$ between Alice and Bob, the two-player communication complexity is $\widetilde O(k)$ (this was recently shown true for some similar functions).

So, my question is: are there any simple, natural functions $g : \{0,1\}^k \times \ldots \times \{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$ for which these types of complexity results hold? Namely, any two-player version of the problem is easy (i.e., $O(k)$ complexity), but the $k$-player number-in-hand version is known to be hard (i.e., $\Omega(k^2)$ complexity)?

(One popular number-in-hand problem is Set-Disjointness, but this does not seem suitable because strong lower bounds require each player to hold many more bits of input, and because the co-nondeterministic complexity of Set-Disjointness is too easy for the problem to embed in the $f$ I'm interested in. Earlier, my interest in this same $f$ spurred [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51844/natural-hard-communication-problems-with-both-nondeterministic-and-co-nondetermi), which I would also still appreciate answers to, since the functions brought up in that thread are still somewhat unwieldy. However, if my current suspicion about the two-player protocols for $f$ is correct, then the thing that my prior question asks for will be too strong to possibly work: I'd still need something only hard specifically for $k$-player number-in-hand where each player holds $k$ bits.)